# AngularJS isn`t working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

after watching this presentation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImR0zo1tA_I) I wanted to try Angular JS. I copied the code, exactly what was on the screen, but i doesn't work. I tried it in my browser, in my page (http://thecodemaker.com.pl), I was doing research about AngularJS but it still doesn`t want to work. 
Code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="basicApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
 
    </head>
    
<body ng-controller="TodoController">
    <form>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                   <h1 class="panel-title"><b>ToDo List</b></h1> 
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat = "todo in todos">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox"> {{todo}}
                            </label>
                                <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="control-label invisible">Enter Task</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-primary"></input>
                <button type="button" class="close form-control-feedback text-muted">&plusmn;</button>
            </div>
        
            <div class="alert alert-info">Enter new task to get started</div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">Maximum number of tasks allowed : 5</div>
        
        </div>
    </form>
    
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module("basicApp", [])
    .controller("TodoController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.todos =['Buil an atomic bomb','Sell it on ebay']
    }
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a lot wrong with your snippet. For one, your submit/add button is not bound to an event listener or anything so it's not doing anything that you'd want (like adding an item to the property on your controller's $scope).

Check out the Todo example on Angular's official website, it's more up to date.

https://angularjs.org/ (scroll down).

Here's the video for it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuiHuZq_cg4

Comment: I know that for now my buttons are doing nothing. For now I want to be able to use ng-repeat to show the tasks.

Comment: Oh right, should've said so in your question! I honestly think the easiest way to fix this problem is to use a different tutorial to learn the basics of AngularJS first before trying to use Bootstrap with it. There's a lot wrong with your current copy & pasted snippet so it's not a matter of answering one problem, there's more. The page I linked to should help a lot more.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely watch this video.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error : `Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`, which means you need to add jQuery library to your project, required by `bootstrap.js`

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Angular 1.3.x, you can no longer declare a controller as a generic global function on window.  Controllers must now use the more current form of component declaration.

```
<script>
    angular.module("basicApp", [])
    .controller("TodoController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.todos =['Buil an atomic bomb','Sell it on ebay']
    }
</script>
```

In the HTML, change `ng-app=""` to `ng-app="basicApp`.